# How to model a multi-valued attribute in a dimensional model

Tags: hive, google-bigquery, amazon-redshift, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

I am working on a problem where product dimension has a multi value attribute.

```
product_dim     
id  name            colours             cost_price
1   Arrow-Shirt     Blue,black          $20
2   Gap-Shirt       Red,Yellow,Black    $25
3   TommyHF Shirt   Blue,White          $21
```

Here a row in product_dim is a single product which has been labelled with multiple colours. The value for colours attribute is multi valued.

```
store_dim
id  name        location
1   Amazon      SF
2   Gap Store   Sunnyvale
```

```
sales_fact
product_id  store_id    date        quantity    sale_amount  customer_id
1           1           1Jan2020    2           $45          x
1           1           2Jan2020    4           $90          x 
2           2           1Feb2020    2           $55          y
2           2           2Feb2020    4           $120         y
3           5           13Feb2020   9           $220         z
```

I want to answer following questions:

1. Sales amount on blue coloured products.
2. Sales amount on products with blue and black colours? Should be extensible for more such ***and*** conditions.
3. Sales amount on products with blue or black colours?

How should I model these dimensions? I know that I can use a bridge table for colour groups but not sure how would ***and*** conditions work? Moreover challenges of duplicated are also there.

Also what would be the best model for the same in Amazon Redshift/Google BigQuery?

Comment: You need to change grain of product_dim to "product + color": each record in this table should have only one color (i.e, Arrow-Shirt record should become 2 records: Arrow-Shirt + Blue, Arrow-Shirt + Black. These are 2 different products, and should be modeled as such). Otherwise, your questions can not be answered - just look at the first record in your fact table. In the current design, there is no way to tell what colors were sold - 2 blacks, 2 blues, or 1 black + blue. You need to solve this problem first.

Comment: 1. product_dim can definitely have a grain at (product, colour) level. But still I am not sure how do I answer this question: Sales amount on products with blue and black colours?
2. Also, If I join the sales_fact with product_dim, my resulting fact may have double counts. How do I avoid that?

Comment: @RADO, I understand your point. But aren't dimensions supposed to serve the same purpose? To me product colours are attributes of the product dimension. Suppose somebody forgot to label one of the colour on shirt. This type of change can be type-1 change in the dimension and should reflect after that label is applied. If I keep colour in fact table, I would not be able to capture this in any way.

Comment: Sorry, I probably did not make the model clear. product_id=3 is a single shirt. It does not mean a shirts in blue colour and another in white. Rather it means that a single shirt has been labelled with multiple colours.

Comment: And the answer to your questions: for product_id=3, 9 items were sold for both blue and white colour.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Is the number of colors known/stable, or new colors are added all the time (not combinations, but unique colors)?

Comment: colour can be added as and when needed. But does the solution change with a constant set of colours?

Comment: @RADO, Any more pointers?